# Swiftui image cropper and rotate doesn't work

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0
    @State private var cropRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    @State var image: UIImage
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    rotationAngle += 90
                }
            }) {
                Text("Rotate")
            }
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {

                    let cropRects = CGRect(
                        x: cropRect.origin.x, y: cropRect.origin.y, width: cropRect.maxX,
                        height: cropRect.maxY)
                    let cgImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: cropRects)
                    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
                    image = croppedImage
                }
            }) {
                Text("Crop")
            }
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAngle))
                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.8))
                        .position(x: self.cropRect.midX, y: self.cropRect.midY)
                        .frame(width: cropRect.size.width, height: cropRect.size.height)
                        //          .scaledToFit()
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAngle))

                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    let x = value.location.x - (self.cropRect.width / 2)
                                    let y = value.location.y - (self.cropRect.height / 2)
                                    let maxX = geo.size.width - self.cropRect.width
                                    let maxY = geo.size.height - self.cropRect.height

                                    self.cropRect.origin.x = min(max(x, 0), maxX)
                                    self.cropRect.origin.y = min(max(y, 0), maxY)

                                }
                        ).onAppear {
                            cropRect = CGRect(
                                x: 0, y: 0, width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                        }
                }
            }.frame(height: 500)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to create image cropper to crop and rotate image, however I've got three problems with the code:

1. if I rotate the image the image can be cropped with the view background(the image become shorter in height so the crop is now out of bounds)
2. the crop doesn't capture the rectangle position
3. The rectangle cant be resized

many ways but nothing worked`

Comment: I see a little inconsistency: cropping produces a new image, rotating, however, doesn't, it just applies a rotation effect on the view. Is that a part of the design or should all operations produce new image or, alternatively, should all operations just apply effects?

Comment: The rotating is part of the design , and only the crop button need to produce new image

Comment: If I understand your idea correctly, you need a simple image editor where you have a crop area and you can then drag, rotate and scale the image against that area and, finally, crop the resulting image to the area size. If that is the case, I would mark the crop area, move scale and rotate the image against it and, only when I'm satisfied with the result, I would crop the image. Would this approach be incompatible with your design?

Comment: Yes exactly but my code doesn't work as satisfy

Comment: Alright, here's a very basic "editor" that manipulates an image by translating (by dragging), rotating (with two fingers) and resizing (by dragging the slider) the image: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/d32c1b5f691421eb532582fd185d7e8e. Would that be a good starting point?

Comment: That's great, thanks, the "problem" now is to capture the image position and zoom to crop it before upload

Comment: Alright, now that you've parametrized the transfer as rotation, scale and translation, you can write a function to crop the original image based on these parameters. I think, the best framework to do that would be CoreImage. CoreImage, however, needs some time to get into. And it took me a while to debug the tweak the code but here you go: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/d32c1b5f691421eb532582fd185d7e8e

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications :)